# How to easily compute time in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, units-of-measurement

I want to do quick calculations in Excel.  I have a cell (A1) with 50:00:00.  I do `=A1+1` and get 74:00:00.  So, I guess 1=24 hours=1 day.  However, I try `=A1+1:23:45` and get an error.  Is there an easy way to add hours to hours in Excel?  If not, do you have a better tool?

Please don't say something like `=A1+1/24+23/24/60+45/24/60/60`.  That's not easy in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `=A1+Time(1,23,45)` for this.

Comment: The key here is to use the quotes. Otherwise it gets confused while parsing each ':'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Time function which takes as parameters, hour, minute, seconds, respectively.

So to ad 1 hour to the date in A1, you would type = A1 + Time(1,0,0)